# Parameters in Laravel Eloquent pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination

```
$articles  = Article::paginate(10, ['*'], 'pag');
```

What does the second parameter `[*]` above do?

- The first parameters is the number of resources to be displayed by page.
- The third parameter is the name of the query that will appear in the URL (i.e, "pag?=3").

What about "[*]"? I've used it for a long time without knowing what it does.

Don't tell me to search in Laravel Docs because I already did this and didn't find anything useful.

Comment: 2nd parameter is SQL select. `[*]` means `select table.* from table ...`. You can specify which columns you want select from database. For exaple `['id', 'name']` -> `select users.id, users.name from users ...`

Comment: Good! You should post is as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2nd parameter is `select()` method from `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` which means `select * from table ... limit 15`.

You can specify which columns you want select from database.

For exaple `$users->paginate(10, ['id', 'name']);` -> `select id, name from users ... limit 10`

---

**FYI: `['*']` is not fully qualified!**

If you are using `join` in your select, it might be a problem if the columns with the same name are present in both tables. For example uuid, etc ...

In this case you should specify table name in select: `['table_name.*']` -> `select table_name.* from table_name ... limit 15`